# Confused about the printing procedure of array of pointers to string

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char *names[2] = {"Lord", "Voldemort"};
    printf("%s %s\n",names[0], names[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the above code working? I mean, it should print the addresses of the strings it is containing in their respective indexes and we should be using *names[0] and *names[1]. But why it is working though?

Comment: `%s` expects a *pointer* to characters. Of course you **could** print the addresses as well, but then you would have to use `%p`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had an array of integers like

```
int values[2] = { 1, 2 };
```

then what would you get if use used e.g. `values[1]`? You would get the second ***element*** in the array. Printing this `values` array would be done like

```
printf("%d %d\n", values[0], values[1]);
```

You are with me this far?

Now back your array. If you use `names[1]` what do you get then? You *still* get the second ***element*** in the array. And what is the second element? It is a pointer to `char` (i.e. `char *`). And what can a pointer to `char` be used as? A ***string***.

And the `"%s"` format with `printf` expects a string, a `char *` more specifically. Which is just what you give as arguments.

---

If you use the dereference operator like `*names[1]` then thanks to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) it is equal to `*(names[1])` which is equal to `names[1][0]`. In other words it gives you the first *character* in the string pointed to by `names[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

`names[0]` and `names[1]` are both `const char*` types.

When you use `%s` with a `const char*` argument, `printf` outputs the characters starting at the beginning of the argument, until `\0` is reached.

If you want the *addresses* then use

```
printf("%p %p\n", (const void*)names[0], (const void*)names[1]);
```